Count the number of points in a bezier path
I just want to get the number of points of a selected bezier path, but with my script I get ‘<bpy_collection[9], SplineBezierPoints>’. The number 9 is correct, but how can I make it so that I only get the number without the other text?
import bpy

curve = bpy.context.active_object
bez_points = curve.data.splines[0].bezier_points
print(bez_points)


Probably print(len(bez_points[:])) would do the trick.

@Jakemoyo why the slice/copy?

@Blunder does it matter

@Jakemoyo It works!!! Thank you so much!
